# com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException - error in java spring application

Tags: spring

I am getting below exception in java spring application:

Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

It is not coming all the time, sometimes it works fine.

Can any guide me how to debug this error. I am using spring java application
Thanks,

Comment: see this answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983248/com-mysql-jdbc-exceptions-jdbc4-communicationsexception-communications-link-fai

Comment: Possible duplicate of [com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983248/com-mysql-jdbc-exceptions-jdbc4-communicationsexception-communications-link-fai)